# Perl string parse with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I've a string of the format `"501h-1-c2950-0a1 blah blah blah   501h-1-c2950-01.yahoo.com     501h-1-c2950-01.blog.com   %%%501h-1-c2950-0a1  blah blah  _____501h-1-c2950-01     501h-1-c2950-01"`.

From this I want to extract the `501h-1-c2950-01`,`501h-1-c2950-01.yahoo.com` parts separately.

That means if I've alphanumeric words followed by '-', I'll extract them. If that is also followed by `[DOT][anything][DOT][anything]` I'll extract them.

So my final output will have

`501h-1-c2950-0a1,501h-1-c2950-01.yahoo.com,501h-1-c2950-01.blog.com,501h-1-c2950-0a1,501h-1-c2950-01,501h-1-c2950-01`.

I tried many regex with failure to do. Any help?

Comment: What's the regex that came the closest to your goal?

Comment: I just ignored the [DOT][Anything] parts now. for that I used /(([\d\w])+(\-[\d\w]+)*)[\s]+/g with no so good output.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and then explain why that doesn't fit your needs.  Does it miss some data?  Does it get too much?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, where `$s` is your input string:

```
my @arr = $s =~ /([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+-[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/g;
```

Here, the regex is checking a mandatory hyphen `-` is in between the sequence of alphanumerics, dot, hyphen.

Comment: one problem is it also accepts anything of the format "-----------------------". How to fix that?

Comment: Just add `(?!-+\S)` at the beginning of your regex!